# Are these sentences completely different in terms of context or just matter of choice?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, tense-agreement, past-continuous

Sentences:

To me, they convey the same context *(process was interrupted by some event but 1st shows us sequence of events while 2nd shows just inevitable fact of interruption of the process)*

> I **had been** doing great without you until I saw your eyes
>
> I **was** doing great without you until I saw your eyes

Question:

Are these sentences completely different in terms of context, or just matter of choice?

Comment: Different ways to essentially say the same thing.

Comment: "Don't use the perfect unless you have to," as the saying goes.

Comment: The past perfect *situates* the statement at a point in time in the past.  *I was doing fine until you showed up.* ... *I had been doing fine until you showed up.*  The second event is being portrayed in direct explicit relation to an earlier state. With the simple past, the two events are only implicitly related.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Did you want to say _With the **past continuous** , the two events are only implicitly related_

Comment: No, I'm saying that when both verbs are in the past (as distinct from one being past perfect, the other past or past continuous), the *tenses*  do not establish an explicit chronological relationship between the two events.  Other time-elements in the sentence may do so, but the tenses themselves do not. In metaphorical terms: the perfect (present perfect, past perfect) looks back over its shoulder. The torso is oriented to its then present, with the head sideways, taking in both the then-present and the past in peripheral vision.

Comment: It is a matter of choice *because* they signify different things.

Answer (score 1):

In the first sentence (*I had been doing great without you until I saw your eyes.*) you are using two signals to indicate that your action had started earlier and was in progress up to the time of the event where you saw the eyes.

First, you use the past perfect continuous

> We use the past perfect continuous to talk about actions or events
>   which started before a particular time in the past and were still in
>   progress up to that time in the past
>   http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/past/past-perfect-continuous-i-had-been-working

Additionally, you use the preposition *until*

> up to the time that or when; till:
>   http://www.dictionary.com/browse/until?s=t

You don't need both of these signals - only one or the other will do.  So you can change the past perfect continuous tense to simple past but keep the word *until* and you will retain the meaning because you still have one of the two signals:  *I did great without you until I saw your eyes.*

You can also remove the word *until* and keep the past perfect continuous and you will again retain the meaning because you still have one of the two signals:  *I had been doing great without you and I saw your eyes.*

But what you cannot do is remove both signals:  the sentence *I did great without you and I saw your eyes* doesn't retain the meaning you intend because now both of the signals have been removed.

Now, you also asked about past continuous: *I was doing great without you until I saw your eyes.*

> The past continuous describes actions or events in a time before now,
>   which began in the past and is still going on at the time of speaking.
>   In other words, it expresses an unfinished or incomplete action in the
>   past.
>
> It is used: **[I included the most relevant]** ◾ to describe an
>   unfinished action that was interrupted by another event or action,
>   e.g. "I was having a beautiful dream when the alarm clock rang."
>   http://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/past-continuous-tense/

So, since you have a situation where one event is being interrupted by another event this allows you to use the past continuous or the past perfect continuous interchangeably *in this case* but there are other cases where you cannot substitute the past continuous for the past perfect continuous.